# How to write EJB 3.1 client for WebSphere 8.5?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, ejb-3.1

I'm facing problem while doing lookup for EJB 3.1 deployed on WebSphere 8.5.

Please suggest me :

1. What are all libraries i need to include in classpath?
2. How to construct lookup string?
3. Is there any settings needs to be changed at Server side?

Note : I'm using Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This :

1. Add `com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.5.0.jar` and `com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar` jars to classpath of client application.
2. Generate client stub by running `createEJBStubs.sh` script.

   `createEJBStubs.sh` script found under `<WAS_HOME>/bin` directory.

   Syntax : `./createEJBStubs.sh <ejbJarName>.jar`
3. Add generated jar to the client application's classpath.
4. Provide custom `JNDI` name to your `EJB` as follows :

   Open WebSphere console, on the left side panel click on `Applications>All applications`.

   Click on your deployed application.

   Click on `Bind EJB Business` under `Enterprise Java Bean Properties`. 

   Set custom `JNDI` name for your `EJB` under `JNDI name` column. e.g. `customLookupString`

Sample Client Code :

```
public class WebSphereClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
        props.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2818");
        TestBeanRemote bean = null;
        Object obj;
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
            obj= ctx.lookup("customLookupString");
            if (obj instanceof TestBeanRemote) {
                bean = (TestBeanRemote) obj;
            }
            System.out.println("Name : "+bean.getName());
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Above code and process worked for me.

Comment: This is the only example code that I could find that was easy to understand for a person learning to write their first EJB. Nice code.

Answer (score 5):

Check this page [Running the IBM Thin Client for Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tcli_ejbthinclient.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-8-2-17-0-3&lang=en)  for more details.

> What are all libraries i need to include in classpath?

You will need `com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.5.0.jar` (located in `app_server_root\runtimes`) and the `endorsed_apis_8.5.0.jar` (located in app_server_root\runtimes\endorsed). Copy endoresed jar to `JAVA_JRE\lib\endorsed`

> How to construct lookup string?

Invoke your application like this:

```
<java_install_root>\bin\java  
-classpath com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.5.0.jar;<list_of_your_application_jars_and_classes> 
-Djava.naming.provider.url=iiop://<your_application_server_machine_name>:<orbPort>
<fully_qualified_class_name_to_run>
```

If you have security enabled on your server and SSL required, you will need add following:

```
-Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=file:///home/user1/ssl.client.props
-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:///home/user1/sas.client.props
```

you can find these files in your WebSphere installation files, in `PROFILE_ROOT\properties`

Comment: The recommendation of using `<your_application_server_machine_name>:<orbPort>` is what I was missing. Nice answer.